# How do i make a function work for each button click after i must have selected buttons with querySelectorAll?

Tags: events, selectors-api

I have used a `for` loop and `for Each` statement but it keeps calling the function all at once in one button click. Don't know what next to try.

Comment: You can give an example explaining what you have tried.